# Error while trying to parse JSON using the json library

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse JSON using the json library. I'm executing the chunk of code below, and I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 12, in <module>
    parsedResponse = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 360, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 378, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

The code is:

```
import urllib, urllib2
from django.utils import simplejson
import json

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
requestURL = "http://api.shopstyle.com/action/apiSearch?pid=2254&fts=red+dress&min=0&count=10"
data = opener.open(requestURL).read().decode('utf8')
print data #this works
parsedResponse = json.loads(data)
```

I tried removing the read().decode('utf8') and passing that into json.load(), but that doesn't work either. I'd appreciate any help :)

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `print data`?  It sounds like what you're receiving is not valid, or not properly formed.

Comment: Can I attach the output in this post somehow? It's a pretty long output :)

Comment: Debugging 101: `print repr(data)` (**don't** do just `print data`) then copy/paste it into an edit of your question.

Comment: @iman453: (1) use repr()!!! (2) the first 100 bytes or so should be enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you printed your output, did it by any chance look like this?

```
<SearchResult>
<QueryDetails>
<Category>womens-clothes</Category>
<CategoryName>Clothing</CategoryName>
<ShowSizeFilter>false</ShowSizeFilter>
<ShowColorFilter>true</ShowColorFilter>
...
```

That's XML, not JSON.

Comment: Oh it did. The documentation said it would return JSON, and I'm new to web programming so I kinda assumed it was JSON. Thanks :)

Comment: Some quick Googling seems to indicate that just appending `&format=json2` to that URL should give you JSON, if that's the format you want. [This](http://api.shopstyle.com/action/apiSearch?pid=2254&fts=red+dress&min=0&count=10&format=json2) is the URL you had in your snippet, but in JSON format.

Comment: Thanks John! I appreciate your help (and also feel a little stupid for posting this...should have researched more heh)

Comment: +1 For the excellent comment, rather than the obvious answer :)

Answer (score 1):

is data null?
is data not proper JSON?

from your URL it seems that its outputting XML not JSON tho.

if you can post the output of `data` that would help